# Setting Higher Z-Index for Sprite

Tags: libgdx, sprites

For my game, I have to set highest z index for my sprite.
At present, I wrote following code but didn't work for me.

```
    Sprite houseSprite = new Sprite(pX, pY,
            textureManager.houseBgRegion.deepCopy(),
            mVertexBufferObjectManager);
    attachChild(houseSprite);
    houseSprite.setZIndex(500);
    sortChildren();
```

My requirement did not satisfied with setting sprite in the HUD. So any how I have to apply highest z index. Also in my game sprites are dynamically generated as per game play.

So members please share your thoughts.

Comment: LibGDX, Cocos2D or AndEngine? Choose just one tag @Siddharth, please

Comment: Okay, I was new at that time so don't know much more things.

Comment: Still didn't change the tags. Hello, compatriot! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are either asking, how to set z-index in the scene higher than a z-index in the HUD, or how to set the highest z-index in the scene.

If it is the first option, bad news. There are three layers that have separate z-index. Background, the scene itself and HUD. Actually each Entity can be a layer with their own z-index. Background is always rendered first, then the scene and then HUD. If you set z-index to anything in the scene, HUD and its entities will always be rendered on top of it.

If you are interested in highest z-index in the current scene itself, after you sort the children by the zIndex, simply call

```
int max zIndex = getLastChild().getZIndex();
```

That child has the highest zIndex by definition.

Comment: Second option is correct as per my situation. As per your suggestion, I have to each time set z-index when new sprite added to the scene.

Comment: At last I adopt this option for my game.So I mark it as correct but I have other solution that become useful to other members. http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/setting-higher-zindex-t12465.html